# Contour with steepest descent and ascent

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, gradient-descent

As a simple example, consider the complex-valued function $S[x]=x^2$, where $x\in\mathbb{C}$. The critical point corresponds to $\partial_x S=0$ which has the solution $x=0$. Now consider the quantity ${\rm Re}[iS[x]]$, which can be easily computed to be,
$${\rm Re}[iS[x]]={\rm Re}\left[i\left({\rm Re}[x]+i{\rm Im}[x]\right)^2\right]={\rm Re}\left[-2{\rm Re}[x]{\rm Im}[x]+i\left({\rm Re}[x]^2-{\rm Im}[x]^2\right)\right]=-2{\rm Re}[x]{\rm Im}[x].$$
Now, I have to find the contour, which passes through the critical point, and along which ${\rm Re}[iS[x]]$ decreases or increases most rapidly. In [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02076) (section II) the answer is given to be along ${\rm Im}[x]=+{\rm Re}[x]$ is the steepest descent contour and ${\rm Im}[x]=-{\rm Re}[x]$ is the steepest ascent contour. But how do we get these solutions? What conditions/equations in general allows us to make such conclusions? For, example we were to work with a different function $S[x]=x^3$, the quantity ${\rm Re}[iS[x]]$ reads
$${\rm Re}[iS[x]]={\rm Im}[x]^3-3{\rm Im}[x]{\rm Re}[x]^2.$$
Then what equations we must solve to get the steepest descent or ascent contours?

**Edit:** The steepest descent/ascent contours are supposed to pass through the critical points.

Comment: How are these contours defined? Should they pass through some given point?

Comment: Yes, they should pass through the critical point

Comment: Then you should think about editing your question and adding a definition of those two contours ... a reference buried inside a pdf is not exactly user-friendly.

Comment: Along the steepest descent contour through $z=0$, $\arg (-iz^2 ) = 0$ giving you $$
(\Im z)^2  = (\Re z)^2 ,\quad \Im z\Re z > 0.
$$ In general, if $z_0$ is the critical point, the condition is $\arg(-i(S(z)-S(z_0)))=0$.

Comment: I recommend you to read, e.g., R. Wong's *Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals*, Chapter II, Section 4.